# Vector form of this equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, vectors

In Newtonian Mechanics problems where the force is dependent on velocity, it is easier to write $$F(v)=ma=m\frac{dv}{dt}=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$$
However this is not a vector equation unlike $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$. Is there some way to write $F=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$ as a vector equation?

I'm asking this because I'm attempting to solve a problem where the force is directed opposite to the velocity, so if I had a vector equation, I could solve the problem in one go. At the present moment, what I'm doing is check when the velocity is along which direction (for example $\hat{i}$ or $-\hat{i}$) and put the force as it's negative manually and then integrating separately each such part.

Please comment if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one component you have:
\begin{align} F_i &= ma_i\\
&= m\frac{dv_i}{dt}\\
&= m\sum_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{dx_j}{dt}\\
&= m\nabla v_i\cdot \vec{v} \end{align}
where $\nabla$ is the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) operator. And so in vector form:
$$ \vec{F}=m\frac{d\vec{v}}{d\vec{x}}\vec{v} $$
where $d\vec{v}/d\vec{x}$ is the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) (which is  a matrix).